# save a gif with ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hi I'm tending to save a gif,base64 encoded,on the server using Javascript and PHP. The problem is that every time I try to open the created file I get the error "File does not appear to be a GIF file"
At first I thought the POST method would cut some characters but the base64 string has the same length on both the client and server side. Thanks for your help.

*Javascript*

```
$('#serverside').click(function () {
    var gifsrc = document.getElementById("gif").src;
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./src/save.php",
        data: {
             imgBase64: gifsrc
        }
    }).done(function (o) {
        console.log('ok');

    });
})
```

*PHP*

```
<?php

define('UPLOAD_DIR', getcwd());
$base64 = $_POST['imgBase64'];
$img = base64_decode($base64);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.gif';
file_put_contents($file,$img);
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("gif").src` will return the img url, not the data source

Comment: If you are reading the image like this, `document.getElementById("gif").src`, then I suppose you got a [Data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) here. Which means, you can not just decode the _full_ value as Base64, you need to cut of the prefix first.

Comment: you're right, thanks

` var gif = gifsrc.slice(22);`